# Biblatex-chicago formatting: no period after "a" and "b" sources for same author same year

Tags: biblatex

Thanks for so much help from the community I've gotten so far.  This is my first time to ask a question since I am really stuck this time.  I have quite an advanced template using biblatex-chicago and authordate style citations, but there is one customization that I cannot seem to find any code to solve.  I would like periods after each block, so I am using the code as below.  However, the problem is that I do NOT want a period after the year if there are "a" and "b" sources for a given author/year.  Please see the below MWE if this is not clear.  It seems the easiest way to achieve this would be to add some code telling biblatex-chicago to make an exception to the period rule in the case I am specifying.

If you run the MWE you will see the behavior is quite strange, as there is not a period after the year in the "a" citation, but there IS a period after the year in the "b" citation.  I really appreciate any help anyone can offer!  I look forward to participating in the community.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibtex.bib}
@online{citekey1,
    title = {Book Title One},
    author = {Last, First},
    date = {1984},
}
@online{citekey2,
    title = {Book Title One},
    author = {Last, First},
    date = {1984},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{bibtex.bib}
%adds periods after each "block" in bibliography
\renewcommand{\newblockpunct}{\addperiod\space}

\begin{document}

\cite{citekey1}
\cite{citekey2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Interesting. Is this specific to **biblatex-chicago**? If I use regular Biblatex with `authoryear` it is, of course, different formatting, but I don't see the weird period/space in one case but not the other.

Comment: You're right, I tried using `style=authoryear` with `biblatex` and found it does not produce this issue with the inconsistent periods.  I wouldn't mind biblatex instead of biblatex-chicago, but I have added quite a few customizations already which I had trouble figuring out in biblatex.  Am I kind of correct in my approach of using biblatex-chicago simply because the default `authordate` seemed to require fewer alterations to get to my desired result than any other bibliography style?

Comment: Normally I would say pick the style closest to your requirements and modify that. Some specialist styles as `biblatex-apa` and `biblatex-chicago` go through great lengths to comply with their guidelines and can thus be extra hard to modify, that is something you should keep in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex-chicago` already uses its fair share of periods in the bibliography I think, so maybe you get get by without `\renewcommand{\newblockpunct}{\addperiod\space}` and any redefinition.

Furthermore, I have very rarely seen anybody redefine `\newblockpunct` for punctuation, normally people use `\newunitpunct`, maybe then

```
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}
```

is enough for you as well.

Indeed, `\newblockpunct` seems to be intended for spacing via the `block` option (see p. 49 of [the `biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)), although it can be redefined as pointed out on p. 97. It seems to lack of the finesse of `\setunit` punctuation, though, as you experienced, we could use

```
\renewcommand{\newblockpunct}{\setunit{\addperiod\space}}
```

instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
% pick one (or none) of the two lines below
\renewcommand{\newblockpunct}{\setunit{\addperiod\space}}
%\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}

\begin{document}
\cite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for this.  The command you suggested as an alternative: `\renewcommand{\newblockpunct}{\setunit{\addperiod\space}}` gave me the expected result!  I now have no periods after "a" and "b" years.  FYI, I got the idea to use the `\newblockpunt` command from this guide: http://www.khirevich.com/latex/biblatex/  My document looks really great now.  Thank you!

Comment: I tried the first command you suggested: `\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}` and it worked as well.  Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew If both solutions work, I would definitely go with `\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}` (though you might find that no modification at all is necessary).